# ms-search Protocol WITHOUT Subfolders

Tags: windows, search, protocols

Is there a way, to start a Windows Search via search-ms Protocol and excluding subfolder? Following the documentation of the CRUMB Argument (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-wds-qryidx-crumb) there seemed to be a recursion Parameter for that case under Windows Vista, but I think (and tried) that it is not available under Windows 10+.

Also when switching from "all subfolder" to "current folder" under search tools in explorer, the underlying search-ms Protocol expression (click into address line) is not changing.

Is there a way for a nunrecursive search via the protocol anymore?